# Integrating $ \int_0^\infty\frac{(\log(1+x))^2}{x^2}dx$

Tags: integration, contour-integration

I would like to calculate
$$
\int_0^\infty\frac{(\log(1+x))^2}{x^2}dx\,.
$$
Integrating by parts,
$$\begin{aligned}
\int_0^\infty\frac{(\log(1+x))^2}{x^2}dx&= -\frac{(\log(1+x))^2}{x}\Bigg|_0^\infty+2\int_0^\infty \frac{\log(1+x)}{x(1+x)}dx\\
&=0+2\int_1^\infty\frac{\log x}{x(x-1)}dx\, ,
\end{aligned}$$
then, letting $x=e^{t}$, we get
$$
2\int_0^\infty\frac{t}{e^t-1}dt=2\zeta(2)=\frac{\pi^2}{3}\,;
$$
alternatively we can set $x=1/s$, so we arrive at
$$
-2\int_0^1 \frac{\log(1-s)}{s}ds = 2\sum_{n=1}^\infty \int_0^1\frac{s^n}{n}dx=2\sum_{n=1}^\infty\frac{1}{n^2}=2\zeta(2)=\frac{\pi^2}{3}\, .
$$
Is there a way of tackling the original integral using contour integration?

Comment: Yeah, but the contour method will create two more integrals which you have to solve from scratch. Your method is the easiest.

Comment: Alternativly you could differentiate $I(a)=\int_0^{\infty}dx(1+x)^a/x^2$ (which gives a beta function) two times w.r.t. $a$ and set $a=0$ in the end of the calculation (in other words you are looking for $I''(0)$)

Comment: Unless @tired have an easier approach using contour integration.

Comment: @ZaidAlyafeai not really at the moment...

Comment: @tired The Beta Function fails at every stage if the limits are taken naively. Extra care needs to be taken, for the approach to work. I have not been able to make it work.

Comment: Please, write $\log^{2}\left(1 + x\right)$ instead of $\require{cancel}\cancel{\log\left(1 + x\right)^{2}}$ which can be confused with $\log\left(\left[1 + x\right]^{2}\right)$. Be generous with $\left(\cdots\right)$'s. It's better $\log\left(x\right)$ than $\cancel{\log x}$.

Comment: @JackLam you are right. But if we additionally replace the exponent $2$ by $b$ and take limits in the end, everything should work out

Comment: https://sandbox.open.wolframcloud.com/app/objects/998e8e6f-da4f-49e0-a3ae-bf857488da79#sidebar=compute

Comment: @tired, I cannot access the link ?

Answer (score 1):

Notice first that the function

$$f (z) = \frac {\log^2 (1+z)}{z^2}$$
Has a removable singularity  near 0 hence we don't have any residues to calculate. You can consider a contour of a semi-circle in the upper half plain indented at the branch point $-1$. Note that we will have

$$\int_{-\infty}^{-1}\frac {(\log |1+x|+i\pi)^2}{x^2}dx+\int_{-1}^{0}\frac {\log^2 (1+x)}{x^2}dx=-\int^{\infty}_{0}\frac {\log^2(1+x)}{x^2}dx$$

Note the imaginary part
Note that $$\int_{-\infty}^{-1} \frac{(\log |1+x|)}{x^2}dx=0$$

for the real parts we have

$$\int^{\infty}_{1}\frac {\log^2(x-1)}{x^2}dx+\int_{0}^{1}\frac {\log^2 (1-x)}{x^2}dx-\pi^2=-\int^{\infty}_{0}\frac {\log^2(1+x)}{x^2}dx$$

This is no better than solving the original integral !